# Predicate logic, Every boy who loves a girl is also loved by a girl

Tags: predicate-logic

I'm doing some selfstudying and I'm lacking the anwsers to check if I'm correct. So this is why I'm on here so frequently, as I really want to understand the matter.

So here is the sentence I'm trying to convert to predicate logic:

Every boy who loves a girl is also loved by some girl.

DoD = Humans

Here's what I got:

$\forall x(Bx \wedge \exists y(Gy\wedge Lxy))\rightarrow \exists z(Gz \wedge Lzx)$

With B being a boy, G being a Girl, and L x Loving y.

Comment: It should be: $\forall x\left[\left[Bx\wedge\exists y\left[Gy\wedge Lxy\right]\right]\Rightarrow\exists y\left[Gy\wedge Lyx\right]\right]$

Comment: Your translation is correct, apart from a parenthesis problem.

Comment: In short you have $A\rightarrow E\left(x\right)$. In $A$ variable
$x$ is bounded and in $E\left(x\right)$ it is not.

Comment: Ok so by adding the parenthesis I would include x into the last part of the formula?

Comment: Yes, adding parentheses solves it.

Comment: I've never filled a tank with blankets, so obviously this is not a thing that is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are saying here:

If every boy loves a girl then there is a girl that loves some particular boy yet to be specified.

See also my comment.

Comment: Symbol $x$ is not a constant, so it's not "a specific boy $x$", more like "some particular boy yet to be specified". Or perhaps "If every boy loves a girl, then there is a girl that loves <insert name here>."

Comment: @dtldarek Thanks, repaired.